# Geolocation error: ERROR(1): User denied geolocation prompt

Tags: firefox, safari, geolocation

I'm getting a console error in both Firefox and Safari:
`ERROR(1): User denied geolocation prompt`
when calling `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`

I've made a very simple Geolocation demo exactly like the example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition#Example

It is **https** secure, and I click **Allow Location Access**.

Here's the demo: https://demo.footstepsmarketing.com/locator.html

It works in Chrome. I can confirm that it does work in Firefox 63, but does not in 64 onwards. It does not work in Safari. Any insight would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It was actually a problem with permissions in Mac OS X: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029867/navigator-getcurrentposition-not-working-in-firefox-nor-safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029867/navigator-getcurrentposition-not-working-in-firefox-nor-safari)

Answer (score 0):

Look like they fix it in a new Version, facing the same problem:

https://www.ghacks.net/2019/03/01/firefox-65-0-2-fixes-a-geolocation-issue/

Comment: you need to wait for 65.0.2  it will fix it :)

Comment: I'm up to 66.02 and I still get the same thing :/

Comment: Version 71 is still the same too. I changed to Vivaldi, it works there, and Geolocations are easier to change/emulate in that browser too.