# navigator.getCurrentPosition() not working in Firefox nor Safari

Tags: javascript, browser, location

I can't seem to get navigator.getLocation() working on either Firefox 65 or Safari 10

```
function getLocation(user_radius) {

var geo_options = {
enableHighAccuracy: true, 
maximumAge        : 30000, 
timeout           : 27000
};

function error(err) {
console.warn('Cannot load user location. Make sure you gave permission to share location');
}

document.body.style.position = "absolute";

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

        lat0 = position.coords.latitude;
        long0 = position.coords.longitude;
        corefunction(user_radius);
    },error,geo_options);
} else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}
```

Although Firefox ask to access location while Safari doesn't, neither of them return latitude nor longitude.
Firefox and Safari log:

```
*Cannot load user location. Make sure you gave.....*
```

what am I doing wrong?

Yes I gave permissions, and yes I have location services enabled in both.
The code works fine in Opera, Chrome, IE and Edge...

The curious thing is that I canNOT get my location with those browser even with 3rd party pages:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

UPDATE#1
I have tried Steven's suggestion to add navigator.permission;This is the snipplet I ve run just to test if it worked in Firefox.

```
   function handlePermission() {
  navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.state == 'granted') {
  report(result.state);
  geoBtn.style.display = 'none';
} else if (result.state == 'prompt') {
  report(result.state);
  geoBtn.style.display = 'none';
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

        lat0 = position.coords.latitude;
        long0 = position.coords.longitude;

    },error,geo_options);
} else if (result.state == 'denied') {
  report(result.state);
  geoBtn.style.display = 'inline';
}
result.onchange = function() {
  report(result.state);
}
});
}
```

The console says "prompt" but getCurrentPosition() is not executed.

Comment: you need to also implement the permissions API. the error is due to the user not allowing geolocation permissions.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API

Comment: Thanks Steve, I have added the navigator.permission.query(...) from the page you linked. The log is showing "prompt" as a status but nothing is returned and It looks like getCurrentPosition() is not executed...

Comment: Could you update your code example?

Are you using code similar to this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PermissionStatus

Comment: added to main post UPDATE#1

Comment: I am not en expert on FireFox permissions API, but I might be able to help a bit more, but this is just a hunch at this point. 

In my experience, when a user 'denies' permission on a given domain at any point, they will not be prompted to re-allow permissions and instead need to navigate into the browser settings for the given domain to actually change this to 'allow', not even the prompt will show. This sounds to me like a similar situation, though I experienced it with mobile safari on iOS,

Comment: thanks for you help Steve. The real problem here is that I do get the prompt asking for giving permission, but when I click YES it does nothing and the console return the error as I didn't give permission

Comment: I do not see the definition of your `report` function. Does this get updated with the `result.state`?

Comment: result.state returns "prompt"

Comment: and that's all it ever says? It should say prompt at first, when prompt the user for permissions and be called again any time the user changes the permissions. This isn't happening?

Comment: it says prompt at first and then nothing...doesn't even ask for permission

Comment: And have you confirmed that the browser does not have any permissions saved already for this domain? This is often the main cause of issues with permissions.

Comment: Hey Steve, I found the issue. see my answer. Thanks a lot for your support...really appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

Ok I found what was the problem and it was OSX and iOS.
Firefox and Safari when running under those browsers needs location services habilitated from Finder->apple->System Preferences->Security & Privacy-> Privacy 
then add Firefox and Safari to the whitelist

For some reason, Chrome is setting itself into the whitelist after you accepted to share location on browser. The same for Opera.

Hence in a nutshell, the problem was Apple's privacy system which is a bit convoluted. Goods and bads I suppose

Comment: oh wow, what a problem! I'm happy that you were able to solve this issue, as I expect I will also run into it here. ;)

Comment: Perfect - do you know if there is anyway to programmatically detect if thats the case, to help the user fix the issue?

Comment: Wow, this is so helpful -- this saved me hours of debugging.  Thank you!!!